# std:: add_pointer, what the try_add_pointer for in the possible implementation?

Tags: c++, c++11

In cppreference [add_pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_pointer), it is said we may  implement it as:

```
namespace detail {

template <class T>
struct type_identity { using type = T; }; // or use std::type_identity (since C++20)

template <class T>
auto try_add_pointer(int) -> type_identity<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type*>;
template <class T>
auto try_add_pointer(...) -> type_identity<T>;

} // namespace detail

template <class T>
struct add_pointer : decltype(detail::try_add_pointer<T>(0)) {};
```

My question is what is the `try_add_pointer` for? 
I know it is SFINAE. But why the implementation need it here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read over the page on cppreference, you'll notice this sentence

> Otherwise (if T is a cv- or ref-qualified function type), provides the member typedef type which is the type T.

Function have their own types. Normally, what you'll see in sane code is types like `int(int)`, i.e. the type of a function taking a single integer and returning an integer. This is the type of argument `std::function` expects, e.g `std::function<int(int)>`.

However the set of function types also contains oddities that relate to member functions. For instance

```
struct foo {
  int bar(int) const;
};
```

`int(int) const` is the function type of `bar`. While this type exists in the type system, it is limited in its uses.

> **[dcl.fct]**
>
> [6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct#6) A cv-qualifier-seq or a ref-qualifier shall only be part of:
>
> - the function type for a non-static member function,
> - the function type to which a pointer to member refers,
> - the top-level function type of a function typedef declaration or alias-declaration,
> - the type-id in the default argument of a type-parameter ([temp.param]), or
> - the type-id of a template-argument for a type-parameter ([temp.names]).
>
> The effect of a cv-qualifier-seq in a function declarator is not the
>   same as adding cv-qualification on top of the function type. In the
>   latter case, the cv-qualifiers are ignored. [ Note: a function type
>   that has a cv-qualifier-seq is not a cv-qualified type; there are no
>   cv-qualified function types.  — end note ] [ Example:
>
> ```
> typedef void F();
> struct S {
>   const F f;        // OK: equivalent to: void f();
> };
> ```
>
> — end example ] The return type, the parameter-type-list, the
>   ref-qualifier, and the cv-qualifier-seq, but not the default arguments
>   ([dcl.fct.default]) or the exception specification ([except.spec]),
>   are part of the function type.

So the trait allows you to feed it a function type like `int() const`, and it's expected to return it unchanged.

That's where `try_add_pointer` comes in. Since as you can see from the list above, there are no regular pointers to these sort of functions, we will get a substitution failure in `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type*`. But thanks to SFINAE, a fallback exists.

Answer (score 2):

It is to handle <strike>reference</strike> "abominable function types"

<strike>`std::add_pointer<int&>::type` is `int*`. `int&*` is invalid.</strike>

`std::add_pointer_t<int() const>` is `int () const`

Comment: No, it's to handle the abominable function type. The `remove_reference` (without `try_add_pointer`)  is enough to handle references alone.

Comment: Correct. The first sentence on cppreference: "If T is a reference type, then provides the member typedef type which is a pointer to the referred type."

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: To what function type would you add a pointer?

Comment: @MSalters -*"Otherwise (if T is a cv- or ref-qualified function type), provides the member typedef type which is the type T."* - Trying to add a pointer over `int (void) const` for instance. The trait is specified for that case.